# NullPointerException when working with selenium-chrome-driver in Maven without ChromeDriver.exe

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my LocalTestRunner class that contains method that getting WebDriver and also After and BeforeMethod which using it. But i am getting an error. This code i found on the github. I know that i this code can't find webdriver, should i write path to it?

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at dtapi.dtapiBase.LocalTestRunner.getDriver(LocalTestRunner.java:27)
>         at dtapi.dtapiBase.LocalAdminTestRunner.loadSignInPage(LocalAdminTestRunner.java:18)
>         at dtapiLoginTest.AdminPageTest.addRouter(AdminPageTest.java:47)

**Class**

```
public abstract class LocalTestRunner {
    public String url = "https://example.com";
    public String serverUrlLogout = "https://example.com";
    public String adminServerUrl = "https://example.com";

    public final Long ONE_SECOND_DELAY = 1000L;
    public Map<Long, WebDriver> drivers;
    protected WebDriver driver;
    public SoftAssert softAssert;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        WebDriver currentWebDriver = drivers.get(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if (currentWebDriver == null) {
            currentWebDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            currentWebDriver.manage().window().maximize();
            currentWebDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            drivers.put(Thread.currentThread().getId(), currentWebDriver);
        }
        return currentWebDriver;
    }

    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(ITestContext context) {
        drivers = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : context.getCurrentXmlTest().getAllParameters().entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().equals("url")) {
                url = entry.getValue();
            }
            if (entry.getKey().toLowerCase().equals("serverUrlLogout")) {
                serverUrlLogout = entry.getValue();
            }
        }
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void afterClass() {
        for (Map.Entry<Long, WebDriver> currentWebDriver : drivers.entrySet()) {
            if (currentWebDriver.getValue() != null) {
                currentWebDriver.getValue().quit();
            }
        }
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        softAssert = new SoftAssert();
        getDriver().get(url);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
            System.out.println("***Test " + result.getName() + " ERROR");
            // Take Screenshot, save sourceCode, save to log, prepare report, Return to
            new ScreenShotHelper(getDriver()).keepPageSourceStatus();
            // previous state, logout, etc.
        }
        getDriver().get(serverUrlLogout);
        ApplicationStatus.get().setLogged(false);
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I have added some code in my pom.xml but it still isn't working

```
<configuration>
                    <installationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</installationDirectory>
                    <!-- <installationDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</installationDirectory>-->
                    <keepDownloadedWebdrivers>true</keepDownloadedWebdrivers>
                    <drivers>
                        <driver>
                            <name>chromedriver</name>
                            <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                            <platform>${os.detected.name}</platform>
                            <!-- <platform>windows</platform> -->
                            <bit>32</bit>
                            <!-- <version>74.0.3729.6</version> -->
                            <!-- <url>https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/chromedriver_win32.zip</url> -->
                            <!-- <version>76.0.3809.126</version> -->
                            <!-- <url>https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.126/chromedriver_win32.zip</url> -->
                            <!--                            <url>https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/chromedriver_win32.zip</url> -->
                            <url>https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.106/chromedriver_win32.zip</url>

                        </driver>
                    </drivers>
                </configuration>
```

Where should  test-classes directory be located? under src directory in my project?

```
installationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</installationDirectory>
```

Comment: you got null pointer because your driver is not instantiated

Comment: @DipakBachhav check out my update please